# Inform user about progress while UI is blocked

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface

Subject sounds mutually exclusive, and this is probably a terrible hack, but I'll ask anyway.

I have an single-threaded VB.NET application which is setting status bar label to "Loading..." and then synchronously loading data from database which in some cases can take up to 1-2 minutes. Is there any way to show user an AJAX-type animation while data is being loaded? Of course, the correct way is to use separate thread/BackgroundWorker for data access and manage UI separately, but I can't currently change data access model and have been asked for a "temporary fix".

Here are some of my ideas at the moment:

1. Update label (and only that single label) from another thread, force it's redraw, somehow circumventing windows forms message pump (probably not possible)
2. Keep another process in background and send "show" message to it from main application. It shows up in front of application, shows animation until "hide" message from main application is received. (problems with user switching away from main application but "animation" form still visible)

Comment: So you can't port the database call to another thread, but you can port the redrawing of the form to another thread. The other thread option seems to make the most sense to me..

Comment: @chris Sorry, hitted Enter too fast. I can't port the database call, because database is accessed from various classes and forms and porting it would require reprogramming each caller as they expect the call to block. It is not possible at the moment, although it will probably be done in future. 
So you mean it is possible to update and redraw control from another thread while thread which owns control is blocked? How is that possible? Any code samples?

Comment: What about BackgroundWorker would require a data access change? I think you should _try_ that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll probably get down voted for suggesting it (and quite frankly I don't blame people) but this sounds like a job for [DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx).

I wouldn't normally suggest it, but you are looking for a hack.

Comment: Yes, that was the third idea I had but user is not supposed to fiddle with form's controls while database call is executing. I guess I'll press for data access model change. This temporary fix is meant to "improve" user experience, but I think it will actually suffer (synchronizable processes, re-entrancy bugs etc.) more than seeing a blocked UI from time to time.

Comment: You can use DoEvents in combination with setting the cursor to an hourglass. On all your button clicks, check if the cursor is an hourglass and if it is exit the event without doing anything.

Comment: +1. Considering the circumstances, I actually just upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks Neolisk. I wouldn't want to do this myself. But until they remove DoEvents from the language, I suppose there must be *some* legitimate circumstances where you can use it.